# Image src is not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My haml file:

```
%img{:class => 'thumbnail', :src => '/assets/images/filename.jpg'}
```

It outputs correctly in the html browser:

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="/assets/images/filename.jpg">
```

But the image doesn't show up.
This is what Chrome is looking for:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/images/filename.jpg
```

But when I try to visit that url, I'm being shown:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/filename.jpg"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.shown
```

Am I supposed to add something in the config file?? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

PS: I am working in development environment, so I serve my own static files.

Answer (score 8):

You should use `/assets/filename.jpg` without `images` namespace.

Comment: I thought I had thought of all combinations but I didn't try that one. Thanks a lot, it does work. This was just a test, because what I'd like to do is link to an image in a `medias` folder at the same level as my `app` folder (not in it). '/medias/filename.jpg' Should I declare the `medias` folder somewhere so I can access it?

Comment: Note: I don't want to put those images in the assets directory, because they are not so much images for the website as 'content'. It'll also be easier for me to manage those once I decide to put the static files on amazon S3 or else. I just switched from Django to Rails, so please forgive my ingenuity... I'm reading the doc but I'd like to continue to progress on my app.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do `= image_tag('filename.jpg', class: 'thumbnail')` in your haml file.

Also, you can check if there's any image before adding the path by just going to the browser and see if anything comes up, like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/images/filename.jpg

http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/filename.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. Because I am using Rails 3.2 and this version uses the asset pipeline, you have to declare the directories you want to be public. You do this by adding this line in the config/application.rb file:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("path", "to", "dir", "from", "root")
```

In my case, I wanted the medias/images/thumbnails dir to be part of the assets (medias is at root level), so I achieved this simply by adding:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("medias", "images", "thumbnails")
```

I can then access them in the templates like other assets with src="/assets/filename.jpg". This is practical because in my case I just want the thumbnails to be public, not the original pictures.